# Create new instace of object every time?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, object

I have this in my **HTML**:

```
<div class="ui-g" *ngFor="let orderTracking of orderTrackings, let i=index" (click)="selectItemForRequest(i)" [ngClass]="{'active' : selectedOrderTracking===i }">
                <technical-destinations *ngIf="orderTrackings.length" class="technical_destinations {{i}}" [orderTracking]="orderTracking" [groupDestinations]="groupDestinations"></technical-destinations>
            </div>
```

In technical destinations I have `dropdown`, but when i change one every of them changes. Problem is that in `orderTracking` all object are same. Its just copy. 
Any suggestion for how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue by iterating over a component with `@Input`s.

So you said the objects in the collection you're iterating over are the same, so let's take something like:

```
  items = [
    {id:1, name: 'test'},
    {id:1, name: 'test'},
    {id:1, name: 'test'}
  ];
```

If you're looping over the above array, Angular is designed to create new instances of the repeated component for you:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <app-object [item]="item"></app-object>
</div>
```

Working example here: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8s6qt**

If I missed something just tell me.

Comment: in parent component i populate list for dropdown that i pass to child, and when i change on first record dropdown it change on all of them. List is same for all child

Comment: @None oh. But the dropdowns are in each `technical-destinations` instance right? Have you some more code to share (e.g.: the code inside `technical-destinations` and the collection you're looping over)?

Comment: in technical-destinations i have only input of groupDestinations to populate list for every dropdown and thats it